# Why does indexing bytes in Python 3 return an int instead of bytes?

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to understand why taking the index of a bytes object returns an int that you can't decode, but a slice returns a bytes object that you can. This seems un-intuitive. When you do the same operation with a string, taking an index at the string position still returns a string.

Working on the Cryptopals challenges, I'm trying to iterate over a byte array to do frequency analysis of an XORed string to count the occurrence of the number of plain text letters. I thought I could do the following, but I'm getting 'int' object has not attribute 'decode' error. From reading the Python docs, that makes sense, a byte array is a mutable sequence of integers, but when testing in the interpreter I was expecting different behavior.

```
str_a = bytearray(b'\x1b77316?x\x15\x1b\x7f+x413=x9x(7-6<x7>x:9;76')

for x in str_a:
    _ = x.decode('ascii').upper() 
    if _ in counts:
        counts[_] += 1
```

If I set a variable to a single byte, I can call decode() on it. I figured I could then iterate over all bytes in a byte string and decode in the same way (hence the loop above). But, since r[0] is an int, that doesn't work. But then if I take r[0:1], it does? I realize I could just call chr(r[0]), but I figured if r.decode() works, r[0].decode() should work too.

```
>>> r = b'A'
>>> type(r)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> r.decode('ascii')
'A'
>>> r[0:1]
b'A'
>>> r[0:1].decode('ascii')
'A'
>>> type(r[0])
<class 'int'>
>>> r[0]
65
>>> r[0].decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

String Example

```
>>> x = 'AB'
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> x[0]
'A'
>>> type(x[0])
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: This appears to be one of Python3's least sensible design decisions. What happens if you want to do bit manipulation? You have to use C++, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `bytes` objects iterate as `int`s is because they are conceptually static arrays of bytes—integers from 0 to 255 (as per [PEP 358](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/#specification))—not alternate-encoded strings. Alternate text encodings is a common use case, but reading and writing arbitrary binary data is no less important.

Specifically regarding `str.encode` and `bytes.decode`, it doesn't necessarily make sense to be able to call `some_bytes[0].decode`, because in many encodings, characters may be encoded as multiple bytes. For instance, `b'a'.decode('utf-32')` fails because UTF-32 uses four bytes per character.

---

The discussions around [PEP 467](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0467/), which proposed adding, among other things, `bytes.iterbytes`, might provide additional insight into why `bytes` behaves how it does.

Comment: Huh. That makes a ton of sense. I've only just started messing with it and handling data where a single byte is encoded. I hadn't considered it from the multi-byte perspective. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you've found out the [bytes iterator generates integers not characters](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BytesStr#Iterating_over_.22bytes.22). You need to use [chr](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#chr) to convert the `int` value to an `str` value.

```
import collections
import string

str_a = b"\x1b77316?x\x15\x1b\x7f+x413=x9x(7-6<x7>x:9;76"
count = collections.defaultdict(int)

for value in str_a:
    value = chr(value).upper()
    if value in string.ascii_uppercase:
        count[value] += 1
```

Comment: Yea, I guess I'm just confused as to why. Like, that seems counter-intuitive to what I'd expect. I'd figure if I'm working on a bytes array, the objects in it would be bytes, and I could call bytes methods on individual elements in them. This gets double confusing when you can do b'A'.decode(), and b'A'[0:1].decode(), but not b'A'[0].decode(). It seems like it "breaks" iterators

Comment: PEP 358 wasn't helpful either. Guess it just is what it is. oh well